# Thread sleep will it stop the audio

Tags: java

In my program: I play an audio... I want that when it ends, then the next command be executed..

if I use `Thread.sleap`, will the sound keep playing

is there an alternative to `Thread.sleep`?

```
Thread.sleep(5000); 
System.out.println("Song is over");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are playing the audio on the current thread, `Thread.sleep(5000)` will stop the audio. Note that `sleep()` is a static method and you call it on the current thread. So if your audio is playing on another `Thread t`, then calling `t.sleep(5000)` from another thread will not stop the `t` thread. Instead it will sleep the current thread from which you are making the call. Hope this helps.

Not sure what you mean by alternative to `Thread.sleep()`. `Thread.yield()`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything??

Unless you are playing the audio in a separate thread, the next command should be executed once that the audio clip is played. The code snippet you gave us is pretty limited for us to provide you with a complete answer that suits your case.